# Get Wrond Display Size . how to convert to original size?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, displaytag

I am getting display size using this function but i get wrong display size in this(**moto G2,HTC E8 ,Moto E,Lg G2**) device.
but in my other device i got perfect size.
how to I calculate this size?

```
 private void getDefaultDisplay(WindowManager wm) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    display.getSize(size);
    CAMERA_WIDTH = size.x;
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = size.y;
    Log.d("Display", CAMERA_WIDTH + ":" + CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    } else {
    CAMERA_WIDTH = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();
    }
    }
```

device Name calcualted size : **original size**

moto G2     ***720x1184***      : **720x1280**

HTC  E8     ***1080x1776***         : **1080x1920**

Moto E      ***540x888***       : **540x960**

LG   G2     ***1080x1776***         : **1080 x1920**

Answer (score 1):

Its easier and nicer to use :

```
int displayWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

and

```
int displayHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code, i used this in my apps and (in my experience) it always  return correct value :

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```